# VPS - how to allow different vpn subnets to comunicate?

Tags: iptables, static-routes

I have a VPS A (kvm with Ubuntu 18.04) with VPN server

VPN server 10.50.0.0/24
All the vpn clients can ping each others

And other VPS B (kvm with Ubuntu 18.04) with vpn server and vpn client from the first above

VPN server 10.60.0.0/24
VPN client 10.50.0.50

My PC is a VPN client from the VPS B:

vpn client 10.60.0.10

What I need to do on the VPS B in order to allow my pc 10.60.0.50 to access to the subnet of the first VPS 10.50.0.0/24

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up the corresponding routes.

So all your 10.60.0.0/24 machines need to know that the router of 10.50.0.0/24 is your OpenVPN server for 10.50.0.0/24 and all your 10.60.0.0/24 need to know that your 10.50.0.0/24 router is the OpenVPN server for that subnet.

This can be done to change your OpenVPN server configuration:
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/setting-up-routing/

Comment: "the problem" is that on the vps A I have vpn server with Pritunl, and with this openvpn web gui Pritunl I don't know how to do it...

Comment: As far as I know, you can also add the routing information in the client configuration - does Pritunl work with .ovpn files?

Comment: VPS A it's connected to VPS B with openvpn (pritunl) and VPS B it's connected with my PC with wireguard.